# Retrofit нужна помощь с запросом

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Использую Retrofit 2.0
Никак не получается создать запрос. Мой интерфейс

```
 public interface ProductListService {
    @POST("index.php?route=feed/web_api/products&category={id}&key=***")
    Call<ProductList> productList(@Query("id") String id);
}
```

создание сервиса:

```
@NonNull
    public static ProductListService getProductsListService(/*final String id*/)
    {
        /*CLIENT.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            HttpUrl url = request.httpUrl().newBuilder().addQueryParameter("id",id).build();
            request = request.newBuilder().url(url).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });*/
        return getRetrofit().create(ProductListService.class);
    }

    @NonNull
    private static Retrofit getRetrofit()
    {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://site.net/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(CLIENT)
            .build();
    }
```

в лоадере

```
  ProductListService service = ApiFactory.getProductsListService();
        Call<ProductList> call = service.productList(id);
        ProductList body = call.execute().body();
```

Мне нужно изменять id категории. Также пробовал аннотацию @Path, без результата

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@POST("index.php?route=feed/web_api/products)
 Call<ProductList> productList(@Query("category") String category, @Query("other") int other);
```

будет вот такой запрос

```
index.php?route=feed/web_api/products&category=category_value&other=othre_value
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло, правда продукты грузит все, а не определенной категории, буду искать проблему в адаптере